# How to get certain characters to display correctly in Swift UITextView with HTML data

Tags: html, swift, uikit, uitextview

I'm successfully rendering HTML data in a UITextView, but some characters (• — “ ” ‘ ’ º ©) don't display correctly.

For instance: "*abilities – and*" renders as "*abilities â€“ and*"

Here's a sample of the code I'm using:

```
let inputString = "<span style='font-family:-apple-system;font-size:17'>
  <h2 style=font-weight:800;color:0282F8>Sample Heading</h2>
  <p style=font-weight:300>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas congue posuere neque a pretium. Nullam viverra ex tortor, quis dictum urna pulvinar non. In tristique nisi libero, nec ornare orci consequat suscipit. Maecenas quis elit magna. Donec finibus semper nulla sit amet dignissim. Vestibulum consectetur ullamcorper justo. Ut tincidunt nisi ut porta ornare.</p>
  <p style=font-weight:300>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas congue posuere neque a pretium. Nullam viverra ex tortor, quis dictum urna pulvinar non. In tristique nisi libero, nec ornare orci consequat suscipit. Maecenas quis elit magna. Donec finibus semper nulla sit amet dignissim. Vestibulum consectetur ullamcorper justo. Ut tincidunt nisi ut porta ornare.</p>
  <h2 style=font-weight:800;color:0282F8>Sample Heading</h2>
  <p style=font-weight:300>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas congue posuere neque a pretium. Nullam viverra ex tortor, quis dictum urna pulvinar non. In tristique nisi libero, nec ornare orci consequat suscipit. Maecenas quis elit magna. Donec finibus semper nulla sit amet dignissim. Vestibulum consectetur ullamcorper justo. Ut tincidunt nisi ut porta ornare.</p>
</span>"

let data = Data(self.inputString.utf8)
if let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil) {
                uiView.isEditable = false
                uiView.attributedText = attributedString
}
```

The code is working fine, except for those characters.

Is there something I can add to my inputString that will help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try the following

```
let inputString = """
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>Document</title>
        </head>
        <body>
                    <span style='font-family:-apple-system;font-size:17'>
                      <h2 style=font-weight:800;color:0282F8>Sample Heading</h2>
                      <p style=font-weight:300>abilities – and  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas congue posuere neque a pretium. Nullam viverra ex tortor, quis dictum urna pulvinar non. In tristique nisi libero, nec ornare orci consequat suscipit. Maecenas quis elit magna. Donec finibus semper nulla sit amet dignissim. Vestibulum consectetur ullamcorper justo. Ut tincidunt nisi ut porta ornare.</p>
                    </span>
        </body>
        </html>
```

please notice it

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```